# Cannot use SVG in com/toanvc/FloatingActionMenu-Animation library for API level < 21

Tags: android, svg, floating-action-button

I am using [this](https://github.com/toanvc/FloatingActionMenu-Animation) library for expandable FAB. When I try using SVG for the MenuIcon, the app throws exception in pre-lollipop devices. But it allows using PNGs.

Is there any way I could use SVGs in this library for pre-lollipop devices?

Comment: you mean `VectorDrawable` and not SVG?

Comment: Yes VectorDrawable, as in a vector asset.

Comment: so use `VectorDrawableCompat` from `support-vector-drawable` library

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the issue?